# Can I get place details against a coordinate for free?? Geocoding/Reverse Geocoding Api is not free?

Tags: react-native, maps

I get my current pos=sition from Geolocation.getcurrentposition, i have my coordinates now, can i get details against this coordinates without any payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this, this API is free and unlimited on client side application based on the user current location getting from (GeoLocation.getCurrentPosition Method).

https://www.bigdatacloud.com/geocoding-apis/free-reverse-geocode-to-city-api

Read their terms and conditions must.

Answer (score 1):

Not with the Geolocation package. You can in react native using the exp-location package. Find a doc here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/. You can get location, get longitude and latitude, then reverse geocode and return the address object. Pricing for exp https://expo.io/pricing there is a free option.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import * as Location from 'expo-location'
import * as Premmissions from 'expo-premmissions'

export function location(){
  const [currentCoords, setCurrentCoords] = React.useState<Object>(null)
  const [location, setLocation] = React.useState<Object> (null);
  const [address, setAddress ] = React.useState<Object>(null);

  useEffect(() => {

     (async () => {
     // get phone premission
       let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
       if (status !== 'granted') {
         setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
         return;
       }
       //get location using exp-location package
       const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
       setLocation(location);
       setCurrentCoords({
         latitude: location.coords.latitude,
         longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    
       })
       // print the phone location
       console.log(location)
       const readOnlyAddress = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(currentCoords);
       setAddress(readOnlyAddress[0]);
       //print the postal address. 
       console.log(address)
     })();
   }, []);
   let locationText = "waiting...";
   if (location){
   locationText = JSON.stringify(location);
   }
   let addressText = "waiting";
   if(address){
    addressText = JSON.stringify(address);
   }
   return(
   <Text>{locationText}</Text>
   <Text>{addressText}</Text>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but reverse geocode is not free and I trying to get these details for free, is there any possibility

Answer (score -1):

There is a new reverse geocoding service online available.
It's in the startup phase.
Anyway it's possibile to use the reverse geocode engine using http/s requests.
Basic demo of the service is here.
https://feroeg.com/Demo.html
Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the site. The data are from Open StreetMap and OpenAddresses.
Feel free to experiment with it.
You can use you browser to query.
Example: https://www.feroeg.com/address?lat=40.786138&lon=-73.950691&mode=text